# Can't have the correct UTF-8 charset in php/java/mysql

Tags: java, php, mysql, utf-8

I am developing an app with JAVA and PHP.
I call to the php file from the JAVA class, the php executes queries in the ddbb and returns the result. The problem is that it doesn't return the characters correctly. I want to use UTF-8, I have in the beginning of my php file this:
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
but it doesn`t work. If I put a word directly with strange characters, and I do echo, the word appears correctly, but if I took them from the ddbb, it doesn't.

The functions mb_internal_encoding returns ISO-8859-1 but if I set it to utf-8 doesnt work either

I don't know if I explained correctly the problem, sorry for my english.

Thanks

Comment: What encoding is your database connection?

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should prefer the following method if you have php 5.3.6+

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=world;charset=utf8", 'my_user', 'my_pass');
```

The reason is that otherwise, string escaping won't be handled properly. This is important because php still defaults to *emulating prepared statements* for mysql, so, it very heavily relies on the internal real_escape_string being able to identify the proper character set. Setting the character set via `"SET NAMES ..."` will not update the internal character set setting that is used by real_escape_string.

summary: you may be vulnerable to sql injection attacks if you don't use the above method. I say may, because it depends on the initial and final charsets.

alternatively, you can configure pdo to not emulate prepared statements.

reference:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.charset.php

Answer (score 1):

In your PDO try this:

```
$dbInfos = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'");

$this->connection = new PDO($this->dsn, $this->username, $this->password, $dbInfos);
```